# inversion with "so . . ."

Tags: inversion

Is "so" correct with inversion in the following? Is it mandatory?

> Just as the French love their wine, **so** the English love their beer.

> Just as the French love their wine, **so do** the English love their beer.

> As the French love their wine, **so** the English love their beer.

> As the French love their wine, **so do** the English love their beer.

Comment: You could omit *so* and *do*: Just as the French love their wine, the English love their beer. If you use "so do", you could omit the second verb *love*.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking whether "so" requires or is compatible with inversion.

Comment: All four sentences are reasonable, with the longer forms, "so," and "so do," emphasizing that the relationship between preferences is parallel... and the longer, "so do," form gives a bit more emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

All four sentences are reasonable, with the longer forms, "so," and "so do," emphasizing that the relationship between preferences is parallel... and the longer, "so do," form gives yet a bit more emphasis then just "so".

Kipling uses that form for his [Just So Stories](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2781) as an amusing device to attest to the verity of fables.